# Unable to import FirebaseAuth

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin

[image: screenshot from Android Studio]

I tried to declare a class of `FirebaseAuth`.

The assistant of Firebase in Android Studio is giving me:

1. Connect your app to Firebase -> connected
2. Add Firebase Authentication to your app -> Dependencies set up coorectly

When I declare an instance of `FirebaseAuth`:

```
import FirebaseAuth
```

It causes error in this line. I try to clean and rebuild the project, nothing changes.

Comment: Well, are you compiling auth?

Comment: yes, I compile it

Answer (score 0):

`Import firebaseauth` is for ios code, for android use

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
```

Or move your cursor to word that has red underline until it show bulb, left click on it and choose import menu, it will automatically import the package for you.

Comment: I use this import

Comment: I use this import. when I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword function and make task. the emulator send to me ( Failed to post notification on channel "null" See log for more detail). in log  I have this message (1-W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. 2-W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control. 3-W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case).also in firebase console I enable email & password Auth

Comment: Have you modified your app gradle setting to use firebase? 
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android